# Output single result of a MySQL Query with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table 'viewlevels' has the following data (among other):

```
id   |title
10   |Cenas
```

I'm running the SQL query:

```
SELECT title FROM viewlevels WHERE id=10
```

Which is returning "Cenas" as expected.

But using the following PHP script, I just get "texto= " , why?

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT title FROM viewlevels WHERE id=10");
$res->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " texto= " . $row['title'] . "\n";
};
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: sorry, I've edited my question above. I do get the text "Texto " followed by nothing

Comment: What's your reason for calling `data_seek(0)`? And have you debugged `$row` via something like `var_dump($row)`? if you're seeing `textto=`, then obviously you've made it into the while loop and got a row back.

Comment: Initially I hadn't included that line, but following the instructions in PHP manual here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php I added it. The result is the same however

Answer (score 0):

To see both fields you have to echo those columns:

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " id= " . $row['id'] . "\n";
    echo " texto= " . $row['title'] . "\n";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use data_seek in this instance.

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT title FROM viewlevels WHERE id=10");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " texto= " . $row['title'] . "\n";
}
```

Will work.

Comment: What happens if you do a var_dump or print_r of $res?, also what db class are you using?

Comment: var_dump is returning: object(mysqli_result)#1027 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Same result, no difference at all.

Comment: I got it. If I open the connection with mysqli_connect it works. In my example, I've opened the connection with $db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);